# Unable to find ncurses library

Tags: wine, winetricks, ncurses

I've run into a problem with Wine/winetricks, where I get the following error:

```
Wine cannot find the ncurses library (libncurses.so.6).
```

However, running `sudo apt install libncurses6` just gives me a notification that the package is already installed

Running 18.10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wine may need 32-bit library.

You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libncurses6:i386
```

and then retry.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Will accept when the time limit is up.

Comment: In my case the error was _Wine cannot find the ncurses library (libncurses.so.5)._ and the solution was `sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386`

Answer (score 3):

### Run these commands Below:

---

**Wine may need a 32 bit library You can install it with :**

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses6:i386
```

**and then try :**

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
```

That should work..

Output terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below command fixed it for me if nothing above helps.

sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev